# Getting error message upon installation

Tags: database, mysql, installation

Getting this error message just as I am trying to set things up should I be worried?

`0 <div id="crm-container" class="crm-container" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> <style type="text/css" media="screen"> @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css); @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css); </style>< div class="messages status no-popup"> <div class="icon red-icon ui-icon-alert"></div> <span class="status-fatal">Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.</span> <div class="crm-section crm-error-message">CiviCRM 4.6.10 requires MySQL trigger privileges.</div> <p><a href="http://.....my domain name was here but deleted for security...../" title="Main Menu">Return to home page.</a></p>< /div>< /div> < script language="JavaScript"> function toggle( element ) { var className = element.className; if ( className == 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block') { element.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } else { element.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } }< /script>`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why all that HTML markup was displaying for you--that's a bit of a bug.  However, the real error message is in there: **CiviCRM 4.6.10 requires MySQL trigger privileges.**

The MySQL user that CiviCRM and Joomla use for connecting to the database needs to have the ability to create [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html).  You or whoever maintains your server will need to grant that permission to your database user before you proceed.